# Which lock function to use to prevent a file from being deleted while locked?

Tags: c++, macos, locking

a process running in root privileges on Mac locks a file, does some work on it and then unlocks it.

The problem I am facing is that none of the locking functions that I have tried prevents a file from being deleted even when it is locked. So, it is possible for someone to delete the current file just after locking and create a new file with the same name.

Is there some way to solve this? I have tried `flock`, `lockf`, `fopen`, `fcntl`.

One way is to use `chflags uchg <filename>`, but I am not sure if it's advisable or not to use in a C++ program?

Comment: This sounds like a non-problem. What do you expect to happen if the other process deletes the file one millisecond _after_ you unlock it?

Comment: In order to answer you correctly, you should explain why this is a problem if _"someone [deletes] the current file just after locking and create a new file with the same name"_.

Comment: @MSalters, I meant someone deleting just after acquiring the lock and before the process reads/writes to the file (not after unlocking the file)

Comment: @Harsh: I still don't see how that's observable. Note that the Mac doesn't physically delete open files, regardless of locks or root privileges. So your process can still do the work it wants to. The file is only physically deleted when your process closes its last file handle.

Comment: @YSC, let us say a non-admin user deletes the file and creates a new file with the same name as a symlink to an admin write-only file. He would be able to write on the admin file and change its permission to everybody read/write as we update permission of file inside the lock

Comment: File locks are considered to be advisory. If you want to have working locks then you may consider switching to Windows.